# Error when starting Kafka server in Ubuntu linux

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have been trying to setup Kafka in Ubuntu according to the [quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart), but I am having an issue with the Kafka server. I can start Zookeeper without problems, the problem comes when starting the server with the following command:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

In the terminal of the server I get the following error:

```
[2019-07-09 21:30:24,997] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Error connecting to node 0.0.0.18:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:278)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:256)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:920)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:287)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:65)
at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:282)
at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:236)
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)
[2019-07-09 21:30:25,026] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectPreferredLeader]: Stopped (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-07-09 21:30:25,026] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectPreferredLeader]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2019-07-09 21:30:25,029] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shut down completely (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
```

In the Zookeeper terminal I get the following:

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100004ba9750000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-09 20:46:41,080] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100004ba9750000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-09 20:46:41,087] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100004ba9750000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0xa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-09 20:46:41,233] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100004ba9750000 type:create cxid:0x15 zxid:0x15 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/cluster Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /cluster (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-09 20:46:41,803] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100004ba9750000 type:multi cxid:0x32 zxid:0x1c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-09 21:29:00,344] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100004ba9750000, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2019-07-09 21:29:00,348] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:39738 which had sessionid 0x100004ba9750000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: The timestamps are a little bit off, that's because the kafka server is constantly logging the error. Thank you for taking a look at this issue :)

Comment: How many brokers in your kafka cluster？